# Laplace transform of exponential distributed random varibale

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Let $T\sim Exp(\lambda)$. I want to calculate the laplace transform
$$E[e^{-\delta T}]$$

So far I get $$E[e^{-\delta T}]=\int_0^\infty e^{-\delta x}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx=\lambda\int_0^\infty e^{-(\delta+\lambda) x}dx=\lambda\cdot\bigg[-\frac{1}{\delta+\lambda}e^{-(\delta+\lambda)x}\bigg]_0^\infty=\frac{\lambda}{\delta+\lambda}$$

Is this right?

Comment: Search for "moment generating function of exponential distribution".

Comment: Why you don't just write yes!?

Comment: His comment was before my edit. ;-) So I consider it being right now, thank you.